# Enabling authentication between applications

Tags: authentication, web-applications

I have a set of .NET applications running in a public web environment which connect to a centralized component made up of web pages and web services.

Is there any way to implement a security feature to make the centralized web pages be sure of the caller applications identity? Making a post and supplying a querystring parameter stating the caller application is a naive solution, someone can manually change it.

Any ideas? Tks in advance.

Comment: I think we need a few more specifics.  Your server, which you wrote is application C, and is running in a trusted environment somewhere.  You also have some applications A and B that you wrote, that are communicating with C over the public (untrusted) internet.  What is not clear is whether A and B are running on trusted machines.  If A and B are trustworthy, this is relatively easy.  If A and B are running on a (potentially) malicious user's machine, then you've got a much more complicated problem.  Or are you worried that someone else has a program D they might try to access C with?

Comment: A and B are in trusted machines. But being web apps, someone can mess with javascript, query string parameters, .... If someone looks at app A and sees it posts to C, supplying some parameter saying "I'm A", they can change the post and tell "I'm B". That's not good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS/SSL/HTTP. You just need to enable client authentication. SSL is usually only used in the scenario where the server needs to be authenticated. But the server end can be configured to authenticate the client also. Digital certs need to be installed on both ends. This then uses all the appropriate crypto to do the job, ie. public authentication, establishment of secure channel, using Diffie-Hellman, RSA, AES/3DES, whatever you configure.

Comment: Other answers may also contain valid solutions but this seems to be the best one for my scenario. I already have SSL, it's a small step to implement client authentication with a client certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Assign secret keys to each client-server pair and use them to sign messages passed between client and server (using HMAC for example).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/05/19/aspnet-20-implementing-single-sign-on-sso-with-membership-api.aspx) post.  Good place to start.
Another option, perhaps have you look at OpenID?

Comment: That's not really what I need. I need in application 'C' to know if an http post was generated from application 'A' or 'B'. How do I create a trust relation from the client application to the server application? Tokens and an issuer would not solve the problem, I think.

Comment: Sorry didn't get what you meant in the original post.  Is this to prevent CSRF attack?  See this blog post by Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/02/csrf-webforms.aspx

He got link to Dino Esposito's article and Hanselman's as well on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you communicate with the web services and web pages using http post, you avoid putting the info in a query string.

Send the data over https so that it cannot be tappered with.

You then need to make sure that the call is coming from your public web environment. One way of doing this is to use windows authentication, based on the identity of the application pool.

**EDIT 1**

Take a look at this link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFBasicHttpBinding.aspx

It shows how to set up windows authentication for WCF basic http binding.

Comment: I didn't get this part: "One way of doing this is to use windows authentication, based on the identity of the application pool"

Answer (score 0):

The current situation:

Servers A, B, and C are trusted and controlled by you.  A visitor comes to site A and views a page that sends data to site C, and the data contains something like "origin=A".  We're concerned that the user will change that to "origin=B".

A simple fix:

You control all three servers, so let them communicate to verify incoming data.  For example, A will change "origin=A" to "origin=A&token=12345", where the token value is random.  The user tries to tamper with it and sends "origin=**B**&token=12345" to server C.  C makes a *trusted* connection to B, saying "Did you send someone to me with token 12345?"  B says "Nope" and C knows to reject the request.

This can be arbitrarily elaborate, depending on your needs and whether you're using https.  Maybe tokens expire after a certain time period.  Maybe they're tied to IP address.  The point is that server C verifies any information that comes from the end user with servers A and B.

Comment: The correct way to generate such a token is to use something like HMAC. A random value can be guessed, and even if you ask the server "did you send someone with token 12345", how do you know that the attacker didn't just get lucky? Also, it is a bad idea to base authentication on IP addresses. Why needlessly open yourself up to the possibility of spoofing attacks?

Tokens are a good way to solve this issue, so long as they are strong in the crypto sense.

Comment: I wasn't advocating using IP address solely; I was saying to only trust a token when it's submitted by the same IP address it was issued to.  That's not opening yourself up to spoofing, it's preventing session hijacking.  As far as an attacker making a lucky guess against a random token, that's a threat with HMAC as well [FIPS 198a, appendix B], and in both cases is mitigated by choosing a sufficient token length.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about single-sign-on? (i.e. someone authenticated on AppA should also be able to use AppB and AppC without re-authenticating)

You can do this by [configuring the machineKey for your apps so they can share asp.net authentication tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx).

Comment: Yes I am, this is all to implement cross domain SSO. I cannot see this technique working on cross domain applications as a single cookie is issued to all applications. And I don't want to share machine keys because in the future there may appear a client application running out of my control, not trusted.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for currently uses shared forms authentication cookies across the enterprise by using the same machine keys on each web server. However, this is not ideal if you wish to SSO across different domains and it's not very neat for windows app that need to come into the web farm to use the web service methods...

So, where we have to do this we are using [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)

But to clean this all up and make it more unified and more secure we are beginning to implement [Geneva](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/geneva/en/us/)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe look at the HTTP REFERER field. Under certain conditions this may be treated as reliable. In particular: An A mimic site won't send users from A to C according to HTTP REFERER.

Comment: As I said, this answer depends on a particular set of conditions. There are two or three interpretations of the question and this answer is only valid for one of them: a framing or XSS kind of attack.

Comment: I'm currently using Http Referrer but I'm looking for a secure way of doing so, therefore my question.